# Expected value of the number of bills

Tags: probability, expected-value

Every day I put 1 or 2 dollars in the piggy bank with probability $1/2$. 
What's is expected value number of 2-dollar bills when in the piggy bank will be for the first time at least 100 dollars ?

I know what is going on. Let $X$- number of 2-dollar bills.

1) $X=1$ :

**1 dollar**- 98 bills and **2 dollars**- 1 bill or **1 dollar** - 99 bills and **2-dollars**- 1 bill

2) $X=2$

**1 dollar**- 96 bills and **2 dollars**- 2 bills or **1 dollar**- 97 bills and **2 dollars**- 2 bills

etc.

Unfortunately, I can't think of a quick way.

Answer (score 5):

You either reach $100$, or you reach $99$ and then draw a $2$-dollar bill. The probability to reach $100$ with $k$ $2$-dollar bills and $100-2k$ $1$-dollar bills  is $\binom{100-k}k2^{k-100}$. The probability to reach $99$ with $k$ $2$-dollar bills and $99-2k$ $1$-dollar bills is $\binom{99-k}k2^{k-99}$. Thus the expected number of $2$-dollar bills is

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\sum_{k=0}^{50}k\binom{100-k}k2^{k-100}+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{49}(k+1)\binom{99-k}k2^{k-99}\\
&=&\frac2{27}\left(299+301\cdot2^{-100}\right)+\frac1{27}\left(305-605\cdot2^{-100}\right)\\
&=&
\frac{301-3\cdot2^{-100}}9\\
&\approx&\frac{301}9\\
&=&33\frac49\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Great answer, but why is it that 

$$\sum_{k=0}^{50}k\binom{100-k}k2^{k-100}+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{49}(k+1)\binom{99-k}k2^{k-99}
=\frac2{27}\left(299+301\cdot2^{-100}\right)+\frac1{27}\left(305-605\cdot2^{-100}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

You expect to have an equal number of \$1 and \$2 bills in your bank, so when your total is $\$N$ you expect to have $\frac N3$ \$2 bills.

The hitch for this is that the first time you have at least \$100, you might have jumped over \$100 to get \$101.  There are exactly three equally likely cases for the last step: you went from \$98 to \$100, you went from \$99 to \$100, and you went from \$99 to \$101.

All totaled, that gives an expected number of \$2 bills of
$$\frac13\left(\frac{98}3+1+\frac{99}{3}+0+\frac{99}{3}+1\right)=33\frac59$$

Comment: This seems a bit hand-wavy.  Why are those three outcomes equally probable?  Say the threshold was $2$...so the three paths are $2,1+1,1+2$.  These are not equally probable...the first has probability $\frac 12$ the second two have probability $\frac 14$.  Why are they equal in the given case?  Or are you making a "large threshold" approximation here?

Comment: @lulu A little.  The probability that you will eventually have 0 in your bank is 1, the probability of 1 dollar in your bank is $\frac12$ and each successive probability is the average of the preceding two values.  So the probabilities for 98 and 99 are not precisely equal to each other or $\frac23$, but they share over 20 decimal places according to my Google Sheet.

Comment: You're right about the almost exact equiprobability of these three paths. But you're wrong about expecting an equal number of bills of either type. For large $N$, the expected number of $2$-dollar bills at $N$ is $\frac19$ less than $\frac N3$. It seems counterintuitive that this can be the case everywhere (for large $N$), despite half the bills being drawn being $2$-dollar bills. But the $2$-dollar bills get you to higher dollar amounts, so the cases with more $2$-dollar bills contribute later, and apparently this shifts some of the expectation "to infinity".

Answer (score 0):

This of it this way. You have $101\ \ \$1$ and $50\ \ \$2$. You have to use combination to get either $100$ or $101$.

So the total no of ways you can do it for $\$100$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{100}\ ^{100}C_{n}\cdot^{50}C_{(100-n)/2}$$ where $n$ is even

And for $\$101$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^{101}\ ^{101}C_{n}\cdot^{50}C_{(100-n+1)/2}$$ Where $n$ is odd

So for getting $\$100$ there are total $51$ combinations. And for $\$101$ there are $51$ ways. So total $102$ combinations.

Comment: So what is the expected value?

Comment: There are a total of 102 possibilities. So for let's say 11 number of $\$2$ bills probability would be $\frac{2}{102}=\frac{1}{51}$