# Flipping a coin to get exactly $n$ points

Tags: probability

We toss a coin. We get $1$ point for head and $2$ points for tails (starting from 0). What is the probability that there is moment we have exactly $n$ points? ($n\ge 9$)

I can calculate it for $n=9$, but I find hard do it for any $n$. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: It comes to my mind that this problem could involve computing the number of integer solutions to
$$
x_1 + 2x_2 = n
$$

Comment: This problem is in essence the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456268/the-case-of-the-missing-ninth-of-a-2€-coin/3500175 ... my response in that link shows you how to calculate the answer with a residual life chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X_i$ are the outcomes of each turn. Then your total outcome is $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Suppose, $P(n)$ is the probability, that you get exactly $n$ points at some turn, $P(n, m)$ that you get exactly $n$ points on $m$-th turn. Then the following equalities are true:

$$P(n) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty P(n, m)$$

$$P(n, m) = \frac{1}{2}(P(n-1, m-1) + P(n-2, m-1))$$

From that we get the recurrence:

$$P(n) = \frac{1}{2}(P(n-1) + P(n-2))$$

$$P(0) = 1$$
$$P(1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

From that we can obtain the closed expression:

$$P(n) = \frac{2}{3} + (-\frac{1}{2})^n \frac{1}{3}$$